# HTML to PDF using Itext (checkbox, radio ) not rendered

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

We are coverting HTML to PDF using Itext and xmlworker 5.5.5. Following is the code. Issue is that we are not able to see radio or checkboxes rendered on pdf. What additional things that are needed for checkbox and radio box ?

cssStr - Containing all the css classes. Its string.

```
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(destFile));
        writer.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);

        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4 - Styles
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new ByteArrayInputStream(cssStr.getBytes()));
        cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

        XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
        fontProvider.register(OLTContext.getWebappDir()+"/bs/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);
        CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        // Pipelines
        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(printable.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        p.parse(stream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        // step 5
        document.close();
```

Comment: in this repository there are so many utils example, https://github.com/itext/i5js-sandbox/tree/e53379c073e55def4fb0736778177efd8d0932c9 

look at src/main/java/ sandbox.xmlworker

Comment: couldn't find any example that explicitly make radio/checkbox from HTML to be rendered appropriately onto generated pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason to be using XMLWorker, I suggest you try pdfHtml. It's an addon we released for iText7 that offers support for HTML5 and CSS3.

Trial license can be obtained for free at the iText website. And the next release of pdfHtml should be AGPL licensed and open source (we are currently doing some final code cleanup).

Comment: is Addon available for itext5 ?

Comment: pdfHtml is (to the best of my knowledge) only available for iText7.

Comment: - we need i18 support along RTL languages.

Comment: I think RTL is supported by default (by pdfHtml), depending on the script you are using (devanagari, brahmic, hindi, ..) you might need to use pdfCalligraph. It contains all the logic needed to render those scripts (like "if character .. is followed by character .. merge and create one glyph")

Comment: Also I tried itext 7 with trial license of pdfHtml. Radio & Checkboxes or basically any input elements of HTML are not rendered at all.

Comment: LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile("/Users/ashish/server-ws/workspace/Test/lib/itextkey-0.xml");

   HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(HTML), new File(DEST));

Answer (score 2):

Also I tried itext 7 with trial license of pdfHtml. Radio & Checkboxes or basically any input elements of HTML are not rendered at all. Following code

LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile("/Users/ashish/server-ws/workspac‌​e/Test/lib/itextkey-‌​0.xml"); HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(HTML), new File(DEST));